# class variables in multi-inheritance python classes

Tags: python

I have a `Base` class that stores some basic methods, attributes, etc in it and I've got a `Mixin` that I'd like to share across one or more sub-classes of `Base`. Something like this:

```
class Base(object): pass

class Mixin(object):
    # IMPORTANT: cache _x locally on Mixin to only compute for all subclasses
    _x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        if self._x is None:
            print 'reset _x'
            self._x = 2
        return self._x

class A(Base, Mixin): pass
class B(Base, Mixin): pass
```

Importantly, I want to cache the `_x` variable on the `Mixin` so it is only computed once across all subclasses `A`, `B`, etc. --- it takes a long time to compute this value. Oddly, this doesn't appear to work as I expected in python:

```
a = A()
b = B()
print 'calling a.x'
a.x
print 'calling a.x'
a.x
print 'calling b.x'
b.x
print 'calling b.x'
b.x
```

This prints out `reset _x` twice --- once for the first call to a.x, which I expected, and again for the first call to b.x, which I didn't expect. My understanding of python class attributes was that they are stored once on a per-class basis. Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Are there better patterns for having `_x` cached locally on `Mixin`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you're referencing `self._x`. This is an instance attribute, i.e., it is different for every instance. If you haven't *set* `self._x` then Python uses the first `_x` found on classes in the inheritance hierarchy (which will be `_x` on your `Mixin` class), but as soon as you set `self._x` then `_x` will always be found on that instance. On a new instance, the attribute won't be set, so `Mixin._x` will be used, but it's always `None` because you never change it.

So you want to use `Mixin._x` everywhere you have `self._x`, but *especially* when setting that attribute.

Comment: To follow up on this - you can do calculations and calls in class scope. Just do the calculation right where you "declare" `_x`.

Comment: You could do that, but then the time-consuming calculation will be done at class definition time (i.e. when the module containing it is imported), which might be unexpected. Especially if whoever is using that module never actually uses the mixin class...

Comment: That's true. But hardcoding names of classes is not optimal. It would be possible to have the value of that class variable be a delay/promise.

Comment: You could use `type(self)` to get the class. If you subclass it, then you'll be setting the attribute on the subclass, of course, but that could be what you want.